# Use getElementById for elements that are not [yet] in the DOM?

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

As far as I know document.getElementById('myId') will only look for HTML elements that are already in the document. Let's say I've created a new element via JS, but that I haven't appended it yet to the document body, is there's a way I can access this element by its id like I would normally do with getElementById?

```
var newElement = document.createElement('div');
newElement.id = 'myId';
// Without doing: document.body.appendChild(newElement);
var elmt = document.getElementById('myId'); // won't work
```

Is there a workaround for that?
(I must tell that I don't want to store any reference to this particular element, that's why I need to access it via its Id)

Thank you!

Comment: If you've created it, just pass the object to other functions and access it directly?

Comment: @s_hewitt: This doesn't apply to the OP, but if you're like me, you can't "just pass it" because you lack the reference to it. (You created it using innerHTML or some library's equivalent.) In that case, you're trying to get a reference, but getElementById is unhelpfully located on the wrong object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it isn't part of the document, then you can't grab it using `document.getElementById`. `getElementById` does a DOM lookup, so the element must be in the tree to be found. If you create a floating DOM element, it merely exists in memory, and isn't accessible from the DOM. It has to be added to the DOM to be visible.

If you need to reference the element later, simply pass the reference to another function--all objects in JavaScript are passed by reference, so working on that floating DOM element from within another function modifies the original, not a copy.

Comment: OK, thx all! I though that by doing a document.createElement('div'), my element would somehow be referenced in a list or tree, with all non-appended elements... So I guess this is not the case and that I will have to do this without IDs.

Answer (score 5):

For anyone stumbling upon this issue in or after 2019, here is an updated answer.

The accepted answer from Andrew Noyes is correct in that `document.getElementById` won't work unless the element exists in the document and the above code already contains a reference to the desired element anyway.

However, if you can't otherwise retrieve a direct reference to your desired element, consider using [selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_object_model/Locating_DOM_elements_using_selectors). Selectors allow you to retrieve nodes that aren't necessarily in the DOM by using their relationship to other nodes, for example:

```
var child = document.createElement("div");
child.id = "my_id";

var parent = document.createElement("div");
parent.appendChild(child);

var child2 = parent.querySelector("#my_id");
```

Answer (score 0):

getElementById is a method on the document object. It's not going to return anything not in the document.

On not storing a reference, huh? If you could magically pull it out of the air by id, then the air would be a reference to it.

Answer (score 0):

If you've created it, just pass the object to other functions and access it directly?

```
function createDiv()
{
  var newElement = document.createElement('div');
  doWorkWithDiv(newElement);
}

function doWorkWithDiv(element)
{
  element.className = 'newElementCSS';
  element.innerHTML = 'Text inside newElement';
  addToDoc(element);
}

function addToDoc(element)
{
  document.body.appendChild(element);
}
```